# High and low voltage cutoff using IC555, relay, and an alarm

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

I am currently working on a circuit that uses IC555 as its core component to create a voltage range. Supposedly, if you connect a voltage source with higher or lower voltage it should switch on the relay, cut off the circuit and sound the alarm. But I am unable to use the IC555 to create that limit and check for it. Update: the reason I am using 555 timer IC is because it is a university project and and it is a must to use it. I want the maximum voltage that is allowed to pass to be 6 volt and the minimum to be 3 volt. we should somehow use the trigger and threshold pins to create a rage. the power source of this circuit is 9v. when a voltage source passes through this circuit, it should check if this source is within the range specified (3v to 6v) if not then the circuit should cut the source and ring an alarm.

Comment: Do you mean a "555 timer IC" or some different component that uses part number "IC555"?

Comment: Ok, then what you would like to ask?   
This point is very important to be included in your original post - please consider revising (Edit) to your needs.   
Furthermore, if it is a single IC of 8 pin, dual in line, to make it easier to use in a protoboard, why did you decide to use the NE555 (or similar timer/oscillator) instead of a dual Op Amp as LM358 (also 8 pin), to be used as voltage comparators?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to construct is called a window comparator.  The output of the circuit is in one state if the input is between two separate trigger points (called being inside the window), and in the other state when the input is either above the high trip point of below the low trip point.  This usually is done with two comparators.

However, while the 555 has two comparators internally, their outputs are not connected together correctly to form a window comparator.  To do this, start with a dual comparator such as an LM393.

That component is a good place to start, but it might not work.  To determine that, please update you question with more information -

Circuit operating voltage

Input signal voltage range

Upper trip point voltage

Lower trip point voltage

Answer (score 0):

This image of the 555 internals from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:555_esquema.png) tells us everything we need to know:

[image]

The top comparator COMP1 compares THRESHOLD (pin 6) potential against \$\frac{2}{3}V_{CC}\$. Its output goes high if THRESHOLD *rises above* that, causing OUTPUT (pin 3) to go low and stay there.

The lower comparator COMP2 compares TRIGGER (pin 2) potential against \$\frac{1}{3}V_{CC}\$. Its output goes high if TRIGGER *falls below* that, causing OUTPUT to go high and stay there.

The RS flip-flop's purpose to is to implement hysteresis. When one of the above two conditions occurs, the output changes state, and *remains* in that state until the other condition occurs.

This hysteresis can be observed in a simulation, where we tie TRIGGER and THRESHOLD together, so that both COMP1 and COMP2 recieve the same input potential to compare with their respective references (\$\frac{2}{3}V_{CC}\$ and \$\frac{1}{3}V_{CC}\$), and applying a triangular input that oscillates between 0V and \$V_{CC}\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCeLzk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Input (TRIGGER and THRESHOLD pins, blue) and output (pin 3, orange) look like this:

[image]

<sub>Note: I had to hack the output voltage to be shown correctly here, the CircuitLab simulator's implementation of the 555 timer has problems</sub>

By setting \$V_{CC}=9V\$, the comparators' switching thresholds are \$\frac{2}{3}V_{CC}=6V\$ and \$\frac{1}{3}V_{CC}=3V\$. These represent the levels that the input must cross to cause an output state change, marked in green.

The hysteresis is clear; once the input has risen beyond +6V, the output goes low, and stays there even if the input falls below that +6V point. The input must *continue* to fall all the way to +3V for the output to go high again. Then the output *stays* high even if the input rises above +3V, and the input has to rise all the way to +6V for the output to flip again.

Usually the 555 timer is configured with timing elements, two resistors and a capacitor, and the DISCHARGE pin is employed to empty the capacitor of charge, or allow it to charge up. In this way the device self-oscillates, and wouldn't require an external oscillating signal.

Here though, I am employing only the flip-flop and comparators, with no other elements for self-oscillation. Instead, I am evoking certain output states simply by applying an external potential to the TRIGGER and THRESHOLD pins, and if I understood your question correctly, this is exactly what *you* should be doing. Tie the THRESHOLD and TRIGGER pins together, and apply to them the potential you wish to "check".

Since you have no access to the outputs of the individual comparators, you are forced to have this hysteresis whether you like it or not. You said you wish to detect if the input voltage is between +3V and +6V, but that implies you *don't* want hysteresis; that you simply want to know when the input is inside or outside of that range. That's the job of a "[window comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_detector)", which the 555 is most definitely not, due to the presence of the RS flip-flop. The only other control you have over that flip-flop is to forcefully bring the output low using the RESET pin, but I can't see how this would be useful to you.

Of course, nobody's forcing you to tie TRIGGER and THRESHOLD together, so that they have the same potential. You can apply whatever potentials you like to either, but I don't see how this would help you implement a window comparator. Perhaps another user here can help with that.

The OUTPUT pin is probably not "strong" enough to provide sufficient relay coil current, so you'll likely need a transistor there. It's up to you to design that part of the circuit.